# Hosting nservicebus with .net6

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, nservicebus

NServiceBus [is supported in .net6](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/supported-platforms)

According to the [hosting docs](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/) and [.net3.1 WebAPI-sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/web/send-from-aspnetcore-webapi/) hosting can be done with

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseNServiceBus(context =>
    {
        var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("Samples.ASPNETCore.Sender");
        var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();
        transport.Routing().RouteToEndpoint(
            assembly: typeof(MyMessage).Assembly,
            destination: "Samples.ASPNETCore.Endpoint");

        endpointConfiguration.SendOnly();

        return endpointConfiguration;
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(c => c.UseStartup<Startup>())
    .Build();
```

Microsoft of course have a guide on how to [migrate from 3.1 to 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

But my knowledge seem to fall short as I fail to convert and host NServiceBus correctly in .net6. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also found that experienced developers use the classic 3.1 way of hosting as seen in [Dennis van der Stelt's  example](https://github.com/dvdstelt/EventualConsistencyDemo/blob/master/src/EventualConsistencyDemo/Program.cs)

Comment: That's because I still need to update that demo! :-)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking? What problems are you running into? That sample is downloadable and you can run it and it just works? Here's another example of Jimmy Bogard who actually did update his sample to .NET 6 with NServiceBus: https://github.com/jbogard/presentations/blob/master/DistributedTracing/Example/Divergent.Customers/Program.cs#L32-L37

Comment: By the way, I commented before actually looking. I'm also using the generic host in my demo, just not the Fluent API style. I separated the calls. But as a result of your comment, I'm immediately updating the demo ;-)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/jbogard/presentations/blob/master/DistributedTracing/Example/Divergent.Customers/Program.cs#L32-L37) was exactly what I was looking for. It not only answers my question but also now my solution works.

Comment: Dennis strikes again, thanks! "Answer" and I will upvote and ✔

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, I have a demo called `EventualConsistencyDemo` that belongs to [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTz74m1KbBs).

I just updated the code and you can find the [code for the website here](https://github.com/dvdstelt/EventualConsistencyDemo/blob/master/src/EventualConsistencyDemo/Program.cs#L10-L19) and for a [background (console) application here](https://github.com/dvdstelt/EventualConsistencyDemo/blob/master/src/Server/Program.cs#L25-L40).

Also Jimmy Bogard updated his demos to .NET 6 and you can [find the code here](https://github.com/jbogard/presentations/blob/master/DistributedTracing/Example/Divergent.Customers/Program.cs#L32-L37).